# How to make Class instance in main.py available in another file?

Tags: python, design-patterns, dependency-injection, software-design, circular-dependency

I am having difficulty where I need to make the information available in a class that is instantiated in `main.py` in another file. The best way to describe what I am trying to do can be seen in the flow diagram below:

[image: Program flow diagram]

The issue as you can imagine is with circular dependency. Is there a way to create an interface between `schema.py` and `main.py` so that I can pass class information?

Thank you for your time and any help you can offer!

**EDIT**: Added code for reference

`ws_transport.py`

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import (
    WebSocketServerProtocol,
    WebSocketServerFactory,
)

from schema import schema


class WsProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
  def __init__(self):
      # Code here

  def onConnect(self, request):
      # Code here

  def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    # Code here


class WsProtocolFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
  def __init__(self):
    super(WsProtocolFactory, self).__init__()
    self.connection_subscriptions = defaultdict(set)
    # Code here

  def check_events_db(self):
    # Code here

  def check_audit_log_db(self):
    # Code here
```

`web_transport.py`

```
import sys, os
import json

from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site, http

from schema import schema


class HttpResource(Resource):
  isLeaf = True

  def render_OPTIONS(self, request):
    # Code here

  def render_GET(self, request):
    # Code here

  def render_POST(self, request):
    # Code here



class LoginResource(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_OPTIONS(self, request):
      # Code here

    def render_GET(self, request):
      # Code here

    def render_POST(self, request):
      # Code here



class RefreshResource(Resource):
  isLeaf = True

  def render_OPTIONS(self, request):
    # Code here

  def render_GET(self, request):
  # Code here

  def render_POST(self, request):
    # Code here



class HttpFactory(Site):

  def __init__(self, resource):
    # Code here
```

`schema.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import graphene
import json
import sys, os

from main import factory


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  # Code here


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
  # Code here


class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
  # Code here


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation, subscription=Subscription)
```

`main.py`

```
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from autobahn.twisted.resource import WebSocketResource

from ws_transport import WsProtocol, WsProtocolFactory
from web_transport import HttpResource, LoginResource, RefreshResource, HttpFactory


if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = WsProtocolFactory()
    factory.protocol = WsProtocol
    ws_resource = WebSocketResource(factory)

    root = Resource()
    root.putChild("", HttpResource())
    root.putChild("login", LoginResource())
    root.putChild("refresh", RefreshResource())
    root.putChild(b"ws", ws_resource)

    site = HttpFactory(root)

    reactor.listenTCP(8000, site)

    reactor.run()
```

Cheers,

Brian

Comment: You can pass objects as parameters to functions.

Comment: Can you provide an example with pseudo code on how that could fix this problem? Thanks Peter!

Comment: I'm not familiar with your "flow" diagram - can we assume the arrows imply some sort of *communication*?.  Can you add, in your question, what the, relevant, import statements look like in the files?

Comment: Yes that's a safe assumption. I will edit my original question with some of the code.

Comment: @wwii I have updated my original post with code snippets. I need to be able to import the factory instance in main.py to schema.py so this information is available within the classes defined.

Comment: Why does the module `schema` need a reference to `main.factory`? How and when does `schema` make use of it? it still isn't clear what you are trying to do, at least to me. Since you are doing partial imports everywhere none of the modules are *in scope* of the importing modules.

Comment: `main.factory` has subscribers on the websocket that I would like to be available in the `schema.py` file under the `Mutation` class. So far every time there is a mutation/update, send a publish to all subscribers. I'm not sure if this is the correct way as far as a design is concerned. Let me know if it is still not clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not necessarily the answer you need. But I ran into the same problem and for me it meant that I have structured the project wrong. Meaning main.py or schema.py do things they are not meant to do. Of course you made the project so you get to decide what does what but what I mean is that maybe you should abstract even more. Since I do not quite understand what you want to do with the code since I do not know the libraries.

A simple hacky sort of thing is to just create another file called maybe run.py that then imports both files and dependency-injects main into schema or the other way around.
Another not-so-nice solution is to create an init() function that then imports the other file after the rest has been initialized and therefore insures that the import is only executed once.

But what *I* did was to check conceptually why main needed to import (in your case) schema and then ask myself is this really what main.py is supposed to do. If e.g. your main needs to provide templates to all other modules then why not create a templates.py or modules.py? Or what in my case was better is to create a bus system. This could allow modules to share only the data needed when needed and exposes a general api. But of course this would only make sense if you only share information.

In conclusion: Usually when the application is well designed you never run into circular imports. When you do it is a sign that you should rethink about how you structure your program.

Comment: Thank you @Pixdigit for your very great response. In summary I think you explained nicely the problem I am having is due to a design issue. An API to share the information I want when I want is needed to I will work on this and report back once I have resolved this issue! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For Python functions you could do something like this.

```
def functionInSchema(objectParameter):
    # Add in code
```

This will give you access to the object from the `main.py` file. 
To access attributes/methods use the parameter name, a dot and the attribute/function name.

```
def functionInSchema(objectParameter):
     attribute = objectParameter.attribute
     objectParameter.method()
```

Then in `main.py` you pass the Class instance (Object) as a parameter.

```
objectInMain = Class(param1, param2)

functionInSchema(objectInMain)
```

If you need access to the class in `schema.py` you can use the following import.

```
from main.py import ClassName
```

I hope this helped you! Good luck!